# Maven Artchetype: create parameter from artifactId

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I am creating a maven archetype that requires a parameter (`objectName`) which is the same as the `artifactId`, but initially capitalised.

In my `archetype-metadata.xml` file I have tried the following:

```
<requiredProperty key="objectName">
  <defaultValue>${artifactId.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()}${artifactId.substring(1)}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

which gives me this:

```
Define value for property 'objectName':  ${artifactId.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()}${artifactId.substring(1)}: :
```

as well as:

```
<requiredProperty key="objectName">
  <defaultValue>${artifactId}.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()${artifactId}.substring(1)</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

which results in:

```
Define value for property 'objectName':  tester.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()tester.substring(1): :
```

Is there a way of setting a property in a way like this?